# Loop through array and return the data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am new to programming and stack overflow, so please forgive me if I am not formatting my question properly :)

I'm trying to loop through an array containing three spans, and log the 'data-strength' attribute value. I am able to get the individual spans with `$el[i]`, and am also able to get the attribute value with `$el.attr('data-strength')`. When I combine the two however `$el[i].attr('data-strength')`, an error is returned. I assume this is a syntax error, but I'd love some guidance.

I've also included the pen link below. Thanks!!!

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="trigger">Click Me</button>

  <div id="strength">
    <span data-strength="60"></span>
    <span data-strength="50"></span>
    <span data-strength="40"></span>
  </div>
</div>

var $trigger = $("#trigger"),
    $el = $("#strength span"),
    $counter = $el.length;

$trigger.click(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $counter; i++){   
        var $result = $el[i].attr('data-strength');
    console.log($result);
    }  
});
```

https://codepen.io/joeylane/pen/dmGpdq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate ver the spans within the div and use $(this).() to get the data attribue of each.

```js
$("#trigger").click(function(){
  $("#strength span").each(function(){
    var strength = $(this).attr('data-strength');
    console.log(strength);
  })  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="trigger">Click Me</button>

  <div id="strength">
    <span data-strength="60"></span>
    <span data-strength="50"></span>
    <span data-strength="40"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$el[i]` is not a jQuery object. You have to `$($el[i])` to use `attr`

```js
var $trigger = $("#trigger"),
  $el = $("#strength span"),
  $counter = $el.length;

$trigger.click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $counter; i++) {
    var $result = $($el[i]).attr('data-strength');
    console.log($result);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="trigger">Click Me</button>

  <div id="strength">
    <span data-strength="60"></span>
    <span data-strength="50"></span>
    <span data-strength="40"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use `each` to loop thru your array and use `this` as selector.

```
$trigger.click(function(){
    $el.each(function(){
        var $result = $(this).attr('data-strength');
        console.log($result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Then there's `$().data`, which automatically parses JSON and lets you store arbitrary data with the element (though it won't back-edit the attribute)

Comment: You can also use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a jquery object of the element at that index

Comment: Thanks guys. All your suggestions are great and correct :)